# Prove a sequence converges using the definition of a limit?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Here is the sequence:

$$a_n = \frac{n^2}{cn^2 + 1} \mbox{ where } c  < 0.$$

If I prove this function has a limit using the limit definition, as $n$ goes to infinity, does that prove the sequence converges?

Comment: One would expect. Of course, you should have a candidate L in mind for the value of the limit. Then all you need to do is show that $a_{n} - L$ can be made arbitrarily small in absolute value by choosing $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 4):

Yes If you are able to find a real number to which the sequence approaches as n tends to infinity the sequence then you can say that the sequence converges.

I think,you can see directly this from the definition of a "Convergent Sequence"

Read this page I think it will clear all your doubts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence